# How to show the save button when the user edits his details in a UITextField? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uitextfield

I want my save button to show only when the user edits his username/email. I set the save button's alpha at 0 so if the user edits something, the button's alpha will be 1 and that's the only time he can save his details. For some reason, I can't make it work like how I want to.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var currentUsername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var currentEmail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var saveButton: UIButton!


let currentUser = PFUser.current()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    currentUsername.text = currentUser?.username
    currentEmail.text = currentUser?.email

}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    saveButton.alpha = 1
    return true
}



@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if currentUsername.text != currentUser?.username {

        currentUser?.saveInBackground()

    }

}


@IBAction func signoutButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    PFUser.logOut()

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "userSignedOut", sender: self)

}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

[image: Here's a screenshot for reference]

Comment: use isHidden property of button for show/hide

Comment: Is the function `textFieldShouldReturn` not called? If it is not called, you should set the delegate of the `currentUsername` and `currentEmail` fields like currentUsername.delegate = self.

Comment: you can also set height constant 0 or your height, by default 0 when you are editing it give your particular height

Comment: textFieldShouldReturn isn't a great place to check for user entered something in email / password field or not because it leaves lot of edge cases like if I enter email if and password and tap out side it enables button and then if user taps on textField and clears the text button is still enabled so use should change character and apply ur logic there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use add target for textfield when editing changed.
Here is the code you can use in your class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    currentUsername.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    currentEmail.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
}

func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    saveButton.alpha = currentUsername.text?.characters.count != 0 && currentEmail.text?.characters.count != 0 ? 1 : 0
}
```

I will prefer you to hide/unhide button rather than changing alpha

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    saveButton.isHidden = currentUsername.text?.characters.count == 0 || currentEmail.text?.characters.count == 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    currentUsername.text = currentUser?.username
    currentEmail.text = currentUser?.email
    saveButton.isHidden = true

}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    saveButton.isHidden = false
    return true
}



@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if currentUsername.text != currentUser?.username {

        currentUser?.saveInBackground()
        saveButton.isHidden = true

    }

}
```